# `perl -ane`, grabbing all the arguments until the end (variable number of args)?

Tags: perl, bash

I've got a pretty messy perl script (I'm not a Perl guru) which is this one:

```
perl -ane '($h,$m,$s) = split /:/, $F[0];
           $pid = $F[1];
           $args = $F[2]." ".$F[3]." ".$F[4]." ".$F[5]." ".$F[6]." ".$F[7]." ".$F[8]." ".$F[9]." ".$F[10]." ".$F[11]." ".$F[12]." ".$F[13]; 
    if(($h == 1 && $m > 30) || ($h > 1)) {
        print "$h :: $m $kb $pid\nArguments:\n$args\n\n "; kill 9, $pid }'
```

I'm searching for a way, instead of having all these concatenations for `$arg`, to say something like `$arg=$F[2-end]`

I'd love any help on that :)

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if by any chance you didn't want the spaces around the `::` in your output and were just trying to keep Perl from interpreting the colons as part of the variable name, you can do `print "${h}::${m}"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in bash as well:

```
while read -r time pid args; do
    IFS=: read -r h m s <<< $time
    (( $h*60 + $m > 90 )) && {
        # I don't see where $kb was defined in the original code
        cat <<EOF
$h:$m $kb $pid
ARGUMENTS
$args

EOF
        # Are you sure a more gentle kill won't work?
        # kill -9 should be the last resort for buggy code
        kill "$pid"
    }
done
```

Comment: You almost always *can* do it in bash, but that doesn't mean you *should*. ;)

Comment: I'd use `(( m > 90 ))` instead of `[[ $m -gt 90 ]]`; the `let` means `m` is already an integer at that point.

Comment: True :) Sometimes, it seems people try to write "one-liners" in perl just because they don't know bash well enough to use it. This isn't one of those cases; this isn't really any shorter than the perl. Good point about `(( ... ))` though, I'll use that.

Comment: Thanks for this, I might need to drop the Perl part, so I'll look into some full bash :) About the $kb, that was basically taking the memory taken by a process but I dropped it and forgot to remove it in my question.

Comment: PS: Thanks for the gentle kill advice, but on this one I might need to keep the machine-guns out. I'll try to be gentle, see what happens :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$args = join " ", @F[2..$#F];
```

`$#arrayname` is the index of the last element of `@arrayname`; `@arrayname[$start..$end]` gets you a subarray starting with `$arrayname[$start]` and ending with `$arrayname[$end]`, and containing all the elements in between.  Put those together and you get `@F[2..$#F]` for "all the elements of `@F` from `$F[2]` through the end of the array".

Then you use `join` to concatenate all those array elements together into a single string; the first argument tells Perl what to put in between the rest.

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow. Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: `$args = "@F[2..$#F]";` Or even `... split /:/, shift @F; $pid = shift @F; $args = "@F";`

Comment: @Mark, yes, I had to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @TLP - sure, upvoted. But the `join` method has an obvious generalization (compared to `BEGIN { $"="whatever" }`), so it seemed like a more useful thing for Alban to learn.  Teach a man to fish before you teach him to golf. :)

Comment: That's a nice quote. :) However, without a bit of golfing, perl isn't as much fun, especially in one-liners.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using **-a**utosplit, consider limiting the number of fields being split in the first place.

```perl
($t, $pid, $args) = split " ", $_, 3;
($h, $m, $s) = split /:/, $t;
```

Comment: Your second statement needs to be `split`ting `$t`, not `$F[0]`, which isn't set without `-a`.

Comment: @MarkReed Copy-and-paste fail.  Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write a *program*. Nobody will hate you for it and you might get thanks from people who can read your code.

It would look something like this, although you don't say where `$kb` comes from

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  my ($time, $pid, @args) = split;
  my ($h, $m) = split /:/, $time;
  if ( $h > 1 or $h == 1 and $m > 30 ) {
    print "${h}::$m $kb $pid\n";
    print "Arguments:\n";
    print "@args\n\n";
    kill 9, $pid
  }
}
```